# Amazon RDS, all monitoring metrics are zero

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a DB cluster with the Aurora MySQL engine, but monitoring tab all metrics are zero, even though it is actively being used. Do I need something to do to enable it?

I could not find anything related to it in the guides or through a google serach.

[image: DB Cluster monitoring tab]

Comment: Maybe increase the **Period** in the top-right?

Comment: Even the maximum selectable period shows all data on 0

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. It used to work, today I had to check and it shows zero even for maximum selectable period, and it is being actively used. This is for both reader and writer instances on an Aurora Cluster, also MySQL engine.

Comment: I think what changed is that screen has multiple pages (because there are almost a hundred metrics), so if you go to next pages you can see data, but the metrics displayed by default in the first page all show zero (maybe they need some setting to be turned on so it can gather logs).

Comment: ooooh, you are right! Want to make it an answer to my question so i can mark it answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by a user through a comment, I didn't notice the screen has multiple pages.